# How can I protect .NET Web Services against XXE exploits?

Tags: asp.net, xml, soap, xxe

I am trying to protect a .NET web service against [XXE](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XXE) exploits.
For the underlying SOAP message is XML, it is potentially at risk.

A way to prohibit DTD processing for XML documents can be found [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#.NET_4.0_and_later) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335713.aspx). 
However, the XML parsing of the SOAP message is done by the framework.

**How can I modify the settings of the XML reader in order to turn off DTD processing?**

I also looked for a hook to access the XML content directly, but found nothing appropriate in the documentation of [WebService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.services.webservice(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests that showed that ASP.NET web services **are protected** against XXE attacks.
The framework seems to switch off DTD processing by default.

I used [Soap UI](https://www.soapui.org/) for testing. 
Just adding a DOCTYPE definition like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root[ 
<!ENTITY laugh "hahahahaha">
]>
```

resulted in a bad request error (HTTP Status 400).

To make sure that I did not just mess up the SOAP-Message, I also validated the 
XML content separately.